# Ignore autolayout constraints and then restore them

Tags: ios, autolayout, subview

I need to completely ignore autolayout constraints on a subview. I have tried using `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES` as although posts have stated. This is great and allows me to set the frame of my object. What this doesn't do is ignore the auto layout constraints completely as the views I am setting  `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES` on are still causing debugger output "will attempt to recover by breaking constraint .....". 
How do I make it so the constraints won't even be referenced but truly ignored until I want to bring them back. 
Is there a simple solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS 8 and later you can deactivate the constraint by setting the [`active`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSLayoutConstraint/active) property to `false`. You can create a `IBOutlet` list so you don't have to reference all the constraints one by one and activate and deactivate them all at once.

For backwards compatibility, you can remove them from the view and add them again later.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had partially resolved the issue by making multiple custom cells, one with the views I wanted to use and one without them. I would alternate loading the xibs based on what information I wanted to display. This resolved my problem in a round about way although in the future I will test the active property and see if it truly causes the views to ignore the auto-layout constraints where translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints did not.